# UIPanGestureRecognizer calculate frame origin to maintain adjacent subview position for image cropping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `cropView` that holds a `cropBoxView` subview that also holds four subviews that are square and each have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on them to enable resizing of the crop area.

What I'm trying to do is change the frame size but maintain the adjacent square corner's position, which means I need to calculate a new origin. I'm able to successfully change the frame size, but I can't figure out how to calculate the new origin.

Currently if I pan the bottom right corner of the view it works the way I want  (without needing to adjust the origin in the code below), because the adjacent corner is the top left corner so its origin doesn't need to change.

I'd appreciate any help offered.

### Edit: See my answer below for a sample GIF of the result and code

```
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.cropView];

CGRect recognizerFrame = self.cropView.cropBoxView.frame;

// Todo: calculate new origin based on adjacent crop corner

CGFloat testX = recognizerFrame.size.width += translation.x;
CGFloat testY = recognizerFrame.size.height += translation.y;

recognizerFrame.origin.x = recognizerFrame.origin.x - (recognizerFrame.size.width - testX);
recognizerFrame.origin.y = recognizerFrame.origin.y - (recognizerFrame.size.height - testY);

recognizerFrame.size.width += translation.x;
recognizerFrame.size.height += translation.y;

[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.cropView];
```

Comment: If they are perfect squares why can't you just decrease the sides respective to the amount of points the user pans? Then calculate the new origin based on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out on my own, and it seems to work quite nicely.

Result:

[image]

What I did was subclass a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and define an enum for when the gesture's `shouldReceiveTouch` delegate method is called to determine which corner was touched in the cropBoxView. So now instead of having a seperate `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for each corner, I have just one for all four corners now.

Code:

**CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
#import <UIKit/UIPanGestureRecognizer.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, corner)
{
    TopLeftCorner = 1,
    TopRightCorner,
    BottomLeftCorner,
    BottomRightCorner
};

@interface CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger corner;

@end
```

**CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer.m**

```
#import "CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer.h"

@interface CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer ()

@end

@implementation CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer

@end
```

**ViewController.h:**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer *cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer = [[CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
    self.cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    self.cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
    self.cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
    self.cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(panCropBoxCorner:)];
    self.cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer.delegate = self;

    self.cropView.cropBoxView addGestureRecognizer:self.cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer];
}

- (void)panCropBoxCorner:(CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{   
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.cropView];

        CGRect recognizerFrame = self.cropView.cropBoxView.frame;

        if (recognizer.corner == TopLeftCorner)
        {
            recognizerFrame.size.width -= translation.x;
            recognizerFrame.size.height -= translation.y;

            recognizerFrame.origin.x += translation.x;
            recognizerFrame.origin.y += translation.y;
        }
        else if (recognizer.corner == TopRightCorner)
        {
            recognizerFrame.size.width += translation.x;
            recognizerFrame.size.height -= translation.y;

            recognizerFrame.origin.y += translation.y;
        }
        else if (recognizer.corner == BottomLeftCorner)
        {
            recognizerFrame.size.width -= translation.x;
            recognizerFrame.size.height += translation.y;

            recognizerFrame.origin.x += translation.x;
        }
        else if (recognizer.corner == BottomRightCorner)
        {
            recognizerFrame.size.width += translation.x;
            recognizerFrame.size.height += translation.y;
        }

        CGFloat minFrameSize = 40.0;
        CGFloat maxFrameWidth = self.cropView.frame.size.width;
        CGFloat maxFrameHeight = self.cropView.frame.size.height;

        if (recognizerFrame.size.width < minFrameSize)
        {
            recognizerFrame.size = CGSizeMake(minFrameSize, recognizerFrame.size.height);
        }

        if (recognizerFrame.size.height < minFrameSize)
        {
            recognizerFrame.size = CGSizeMake(recognizerFrame.size.width, minFrameSize);
        }

        if (recognizerFrame.size.width > maxFrameWidth)
        {
            recognizerFrame.size = CGSizeMake(maxFrameWidth, recognizerFrame.size.height);
        }

        if (recognizerFrame.size.height > maxFrameHeight)
        {
            recognizerFrame.size = CGSizeMake(recognizerFrame.size.width, maxFrameHeight);
        }

        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.cropView];
    }
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.cropBoxCornerPanRecognizer)
    {
        CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (CropBoxCornerPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.cropView.cropBoxView.topLeftCorner.frame, [touch locationInView:self.cropView.cropBoxView]))
        {
            recognizer.corner = TopLeftCorner;

            return YES;
        }

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.cropView.cropBoxView.topRightCorner.frame, [touch locationInView:self.cropView.cropBoxView]))
        {
            recognizer.corner = TopRightCorner;

            return YES;
        }

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.cropView.cropBoxView.bottomLeftCorner.frame, [touch locationInView:self.cropView.cropBoxView]))
        {
            recognizer.corner = BottomLeftCorner;

            return YES;
        }

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.cropView.cropBoxView.bottomRightCorner.frame, [touch locationInView:self.cropView.cropBoxView]))
        {
            recognizer.corner = BottomRightCorner;

            return YES;
        }

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```